# Haskell passing empty Character to a function

Tags: string, haskell, char

I'm working in Haskell in two functions:

Basically I want to get the character before matching a specific character in a given string

This is my code:

```
before :: Char -> [Char] -> Char
before x str = trackelement x ' ' str

trackelement :: Char -> Char -> [Char] -> Char
trackelement x y (z:zs)
    | x == z = y
    | otherwise = trackelement x z (zs)
```

My problem is when I try: `before 'l' "luis"`

The answer is : `' '` (of course, before `'l'` there is nothing), and I would like to be `''` or  `Nothing`

I tried passing `trackelement x '' str` instead of `trackelement x ' ' str` but I have this error `Syntax error on ''str`

Could you suggest me something?

Comment: I think you should distinguish between match on first character and no match at all, which cannot be done with a single `Maybe`. `Maybe (Maybe Char)` or `data Before = Nomatch | First | Before Char` will do. Once you distinguish between the cases, it should be clearer how to implement `before`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `Maybe`:

```
before :: Char -> [Char] -> Maybe Char
before x str = initialise x str

initialise x (y:xs)
  | x == y = Nothing
  | otherwise = trackelement x y xs

trackelement :: Char -> Char -> [Char] -> Maybe Char
trackelement x y [] = Nothing
trackelement x y (z:zs)
  | x == z = Just y
  | otherwise = trackelement x z zs
```

To take care of the corner case `before 'l' "luis"`, we have to add a new initialiser function. It basically checks if the first character matches the searched one. If it does, we return `Nothing`, because we checked the first character which obviously does not have a preceding one. Else we just call `trackelement` and use it's result.

---

As Zeta mentioned, you can combine the functions, which simplifies everything and takes care of the corner case you are currently experiencing.

```
before _ [x] = Nothing
before a (x:y:xs)
  | a == y = Just x
  | otherwise = before a (y:xs)
```

Just using this function, you noticed you have problems when encountering a word containing more than one letter which is also searched for (`before 'a' "amalia"` -> `Just 'm'`). Currently the best solution I know of is again splitting this up into more than one function, which brings us back to the solution at the top.

Comment: I have tried your solution, but the result is `Just 'l'` or `Just ' '` I need only the `'l'` or `''`. I never worked with ``Maybe``

Comment: @LuisArmando The problem is that a possible match is given at the beginning. Combining the functions as Zeta did is the best practice.

Comment: I'd add a case for the empty list in `before`.

Answer (score 5):

The answers shown already are good for getting your code to work, but they don't explain why you get the error you're receiving.  The reason why that error was shown is that `''` is not valid syntax, since there is no such thing as an "empty character".  All characters have value, but `String`s *can* be empty.  Remember that `type String = [Char]`, and it's very clear that there can be such a thing as an empty list, but characters always have a value.  It's comparable to saying you can have an empty list of `Int`s, namely `[]`, but you can't have an "empty int", whatever that would mean.

Comment: Actually, the question was edited and the problem wasn't in there at the time we wrote the answers ^^".

Comment: @Zeta Ah, I had not realized.  Regardless, I just wanted to see it addressed.  Personally, I think your answer provides the best solution for getting a working algorithm (ThreeFx's is good, but is a little lengthy in comparison), I just wanted all bases to be covered so that OP understood more fully what was going on.

Answer (score 3):

Match the first two elements instead just head and tail. That way you don't even need `trackelement`:

```
before :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe a
before x (a:b:rest)
   | a == x    = Nothing
   | b == x    = Just a
   | otherwise = before x (b:rest)
before _ _ = Nothing
```

Comment: your answer is not working properly I tried `before 'a' "amalia"` and the response was `Just 'm'`. This is wrong because it have to match with the first `'a'` not with the latest ;)

Comment: @LuisArmando `´Just 'm'`` is the middle ``'a'`` ^^ This happens because the checking starts too late.