# How to return an element before I entered?

Tags: haskell

how to takes an element elt and a list xs, and returns Just the element
before the first occurrence of elt in xs, if it exists. eg,

```
elementBefore ’h’ "elephant" -- should return Just ’p’
elementBefore ’z’ "elephant" -- should return Nothing
```

what's the problem of my program? Thanks.

```
elementBefore :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe a
elementBefore elt [] = Nothing
elementBefore elt [x] = Nothing
elementBefore elt xs | head (tail xs) == elt = Just (head xs)  
                     | otherwise elementBefore elt (tail xs)
```

Comment: The guards should be on a new line, and you are missing an equal to after `otherwise`. The code seems to work though - are you getting unexpected results?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Haskell passing empty Character to a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271939/haskell-passing-empty-character-to-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is well observed in the comments that your `otherwise` (which is just a synonym for `True`) needs an `=` sign like any other guard, but I'd make a few other adjustments.

Partial functions `head` and `tail` are probably better avoided, especially as there is a good way to solve this problem with pattern matching.

```
elementBefore :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe a
elementBefore elt (x : xs@(y : _)) | y == elt = Just x
                                   | otherwise = elementBefore elt xs
elementBefore _ _ = Nothing
```

The key is the use of `@` to make an "as-pattern", simultaneously naming the tail of the list `xs` (for use if we're unlucky) and matching it as `(y : _)` (so we can see if we've won).

When I was a child, my father and I would have written something like this

```
elementBefore elt (_ ++ x : elt : _) = Just x
elementBefore _ _ = Nothing
```

but that has always been too simple to be valid Haskell.